# ORA-00913 too many values pl/sql using a explicit cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to insert data into a Time dimension table I created for my data warehouse. I manage to get the data to output to the server but cannot insert into the table. **I have supplied partial code that reproduces the same error**. I have tried multiple ways which include:

1. changing the row type from the table name to the cursor name(same
   error).
2. placing the cursor(c1) into/AS a variable in the SELECT statement (same error).

I have attached a screenshot of running the code successfully printing it to the screen with DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE.

[Screenshot of successful Anonymous Block completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPKll.jpg)

***The below code produces the following error report:
ORA-06550:Line 15, column 17:
PL/SQL:ORA-00913: too many values
ORA-06550: line 15, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored***

---The following script populates a time dimension table for a standard calendar. ---

**DECLARE** 
 ---Declare cursor for columns in Time dimension table---

```
cursor c1 is SELECT 

    DAY_ID,DAY_TIME_SPAN,DAY_END_DATE AS r_time

    FROM time_calendar_dim_2;
```

--Rowtype variable for the cursor(c1) to insert values in multiple columns--

```
r_time c1%rowtype;
```

**BEGIN**

---initiating loop to insert multiple rows--

```
FOR r_time IN c1 LOOP
```

---Insert values into the time-dimensional table---

```
INSERT INTO time_calendar_dim_2(DAY_ID,DAY_TIME_SPAN,DAY_END_DATE)            
VALUES
 (SEQ_Time_Dim_IDSTART.nextval,r_time.DAY_ID,r_time.DAY_TIME_SPAN,r_time.DAY_END_DATE);      

    **END LOOP;

 END;**
 /
```

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable.  Since you do not show the definition of time_calendar_dim_2 , nobody can really know what the problem is. Why do you even need a for loop?  Just do an INSERT INTO.. SELECT..

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please format your code properly (this time, I've done it for you). Also, read up on how to provide a [MCVE] - your SQL statement is very hard to understand since it contains a lot of columns.

Comment: Provide schema details for time_calendar_dim_2 table

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, this line:

```
INSERT INTO time_calendar_dim_2 VALUES    (SEQ_Time_Dim_IDSTART.nextval,r_time.DAY_ID,r_time.DAY_TIME_SPAN,r_time.DAY_END_DATE,r_time.WEEK_DAY_FULL,r_time.WEEK_DAY_SHORT,r_time.DAY_NUM_OF_WEEK,r_time.DAY_NUM_OF_MONTH,r_time.DAY_NUM_OF_YEAR,r_time.MONTH_ID,r_time.MONTH_TIME_SPAN,r_time.MONTH_END_DATE,r_time.MONTH_SHORT_DESC,r_time.MONTH_LONG_DESC,r_time.MONTH_SHORT,r_time.MONTH_LONG,r_time.MONTH_NUM_OF_YEAR,r_time.QUARTER_ID,r_time.QUARTER_TIME_SPAN,r_time.QUARTER_END_DATE,r_time.QUARTER_NUM_OF_YEAR,r_time.HALF_NUM_OF_YEAR,r_time.YEAR_ID,r_time.YEAR_TIME_SPAN,r_time.YEAR_END_DATE);
```

fails because you're providing more values than your `time_calendar_dim_2` has columns (it's hard to say without the DDL statement for time_calendar_dim_2.

Also, you should *always* explicitly enumerate the target columns in an `INSERT` statement, so instead of

```
INSERT INTO time_calendar_dim_2 
  VALUES (SEQ_Time_Dim_IDSTART.nextval, ...)
```

use

```
INSERT INTO time_calendar_dim_2 (idstart, ..) 
  VALUES (SEQ_Time_Dim_IDSTART.nextval, ...)
```

Otherwise, you're in for a nasty surprise if columns in your table are added or removed or (worse) the column ordering is not what you expect.